# Paypal / Braintree, how to split a payment for European merchants?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, braintree, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm developing a mobile app and a website that allow the user to pay for a good. I need to split the payment in two parts, one to the seller and one to the market owner.

I thought of using Braintree for allow the user to choose to pay with credit card or paypal, but I know that the Braintree Marketplace is available only for merchants in the United States as writed here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplace/

So I have read that I can use the Paypal Adaptive Payment for split a payment, but I know that Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal. It's writed here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Then I thought of using Braintree sdk for let the user to pay the entire payment to the market owner account, and then using Paypal Payouts api for send a part of the payment to the seller's paypal account. But in this way I will pay the fees two time. It's right? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/

So, what is the best way for European merchants to split a payment using Braintree / Paypal?

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree.
Marketplace for the EU is on our roadmap; for more information—and for split-payment workarounds tailored to your business model—you might want to reach out to our Sales team: https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact